# Solving quadratics writing solutions

Tags: roots, quadratics

I am confused on the notation used when writing down the solution of x and y in quadratic equations. 
For example in $x^2+2x-15=0$,   do I write :

$x=-5$ AND $x=3$

or is it

$x=-5$ OR $x=3$

which is it and why? I thought that because x can only equal one of the values when you substitute it in so it would be OR, however there are sometimes 2 roots of a quadratic so is it more correct to use AND? What about for the value of $y$, is it the same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context. Consider these two examples:

- The solutions to $x^2+2x-15=0$ are $x=-5$ and $x=3$.
- If $x^2+2x-15=0$ then $x=-5$ or $x=3$.

In both cases, it would be wrong to use *'or'* in stead of *'and'* or *'and'* in stead of *'or'*.

Comment: okay. So it depends on the wording of the question?

Comment: Also does this apply for the solutions to $y$ as well?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it's impossible that $x=-5$ and $x=3$.

We need to solve $$(x+5)(x-3)=0,$$ which gives
$$x+5=0$$ or $$x-3=0$$ and from here we get a right answer.

Actually, to solve an equation with one variable it says to find a full set of the roots.

You can say that $-5$ and $3$ they are roots of the equation and we see that our equation has no another roots.

Comment: All of it's true, but that's contrived. How do you come from logical conjunction to multiplication? If you want to show that both $x=-5$ and $x=3$ can't be true, then show it directly. This way it's rather non-obvious (given that the question is relatively simple).

Comment: @enedil This is a way to understand why we need to say $x=-5$ or $x=3$. I added something for you.